# Real line not homeomorphic to the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove that the real line and the unit disk in the plane are not homeomorphic. I think I am suppossed to use the following theorem,

"If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection and $X$ is Compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff, then $f$ is a homeomorphism".

My idea is to prove that there is no bijective map between the two spaces and so there cannot be a homeomorphism between them. But I'm not sure that that's the right way to go about solving the problem. Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Remove one point from the real line: you get two connected components.  Remove one point from the unit ball: you get one connected component.

Comment: a bijective map exists since both have cardinality $\mathfrak c$

Comment: The two spaces have the same cardinality so there certainly is a bijective map between the two. The theorem you mentioned won't help you at all, either; that's only useful to show two spaces *are* homeomorphic. Do you have any hint/previous problem that seems relevant? The standard proof would be by using cut points (which is what avs is suggesting), but that wouldn't really make sense to pull out of nowhere if you haven't seen them

Comment: ... The real line has the order topology whereas the circle does not. The real line and circle also do not admit the same metric spaces for the order is recoverable from the metric.

Comment: In what general setting can we say that X is not homeomorphic to X union {x} with subspace Topology from Y?

Comment: You could just assume there is a homeomorphism from the circle. Then you show it misses a point. It is really easy if you use metric space continuity.

Comment: I believe having two disjoint paths between each two points is a topological property. Another topological property is admitting the imbedding of a cycle.

Comment: Only the circle is compact.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If the real line and the unit disk are homeomorphic, then they have the same topological properties. (The unit disk is compact? How about the real line?).

Let $x \in \mathbb R$. If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow cl(B(0,1))$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ restricted to $\mathbb{R} \setminus${$x$} is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R} \setminus${$x$} and $cl(B(0,1)) \setminus${$f(x)$}. ($\mathbb{R} \setminus${$x$} is connected? How about $cl(B(0,1)) \setminus${$f(x)$}?